# How to change the design layout size according to requirements?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-studio-3.0

I'm very new to Android environment. I'm not a good student but trying to learn as much as I can.

I've Android Chipmunk Workspace and I've having a hard time to resize the design panel (the XML file), according to my required size. I know there is a "three line thing" at the lower right corner which you can press and drag to change the size, but I'm not able to get a precise dimensions/aspect ratio which I want.

I tried to look for some option but I couldn't find anything which I could use.

Answer (score 0):

When you split your `.xml` file, both the code and the layout design are displayed.
After that, you see that the device is selected as shown in the image.
Click on that, and you'll see the palette in which devices are listed as shown in the second selected part.
If you want some generic devices, go down where there is an option for generic devices and select the device you want.
[image]
:) Happy Coding

Comment: Did you attach any image with your answer, because I'm not able to see any image.

Comment: added the image you should check it